# Render html (or html output) to Google Drive Docs(word) using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-drive-api, google-docs

I have an project where I have to render the html form output  to an new google docs(word and NOT THE SPREADSHEET !) The only thing what I can find on the internet is about spreadsheet.

The project.

I have an html with form.

I need to get all the data in a new file in google docs when i click on submit.
Can someone show me a way how to solve this.
Hint Links etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try following this code:

```
function myFunction() {
   // Create and open a document.
   // Replace with your own document name
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Document Name');

  var pages = doc.getBody();
  pages.appendPageBreak();
  pages.appendParagraph("A paragraph.");
  pages.appendPageBreak();//push additional data to the next page
  pages.appendParagraph("A paragraph 2.");
}
```

This code will let you create a document and write in the pages. Also read [Document Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/), this service allows scripts to create, access, and modify Google Docs files. There are alot of features you can use to make your document more presentable.

Now, you connect your form to apps script. Just follow the steps done in this [tutorial](https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server). Publish your code as web app, then use the web app URL to pass the variable to your script and save the data to the document.

Hope this helps.